# Most suitable international cuisines or destinations for a vegetarian

Tags: culture, travel

My partner and I are avid travellers and are always planning our next (shoe string budget) trip. I don't want my vegetarianism to hold back where we can go but if possible I'd like to choose destinations where the local cuisine is vegetarian-friendly. Experiencing the food and culture is an important part of travel for me.

We tend to travel a region, across several countries. It's also not practical to learn enough of the local language(s) to have detailed conversations about ingredients or order off-menu.

So which cuisines, cultures, and countries are the easiest to eat vegetarian in?

Disclosure: I'm Kiwi, so America, Australia, or Europe do count as travel for me but my main concerns are for non-English speaking countries and experiencing cultures we're less familiar with.

Comment: See also https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/2569/im-traveling-to-another-country-are-there-any-simple-resources-to-explain-vega

Comment: See also https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/tips-on-staying-healthy-as-a-vegan-who-travels-a-lot

Answer (score 2):

You can try visiting Gujrat. It's a state in western india where most of the people are vegetarians. They have a long list of vegetarian main course and sweet dishes. In a single meal they tend to serve more than 20 vegetarian items in 20 different bowls. It not only tastes delicious but looks mouth watering too.

Their culture is also vegetarian friendly. They normally worship cow as their mother. The main reason behind them being the vegetarian is their religion (Hinduism) and their love and respect for the animals.

Answer (score 0):

I would say **mediterranean basin** has a lot to offer to vegans, and of course to vegetarians too.

Italy is a good place to start, but also Greece and Turkey. Also, I think, arabs master the use of legumes, vegetables and spices; so Morocco, Lebanon, ...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @Attilio. I have enjoyed travelling Italy but I did find that a lot of dishes (in Venice) had a lot of dairy and seafood. Although other regions of Italy may be more suitable. Would you care to be more specific with which local dishes / cuisines are appealing for each region?