# I'm traveling to another country. Are there any simple resources to explain veganism to my waiter at a resturant (that transcends language)?

Tags: restaurant, travel

When I order food in another country where I don't speak the language, what's the best way to explain to my waitress/waiter what I can and cannot eat as a vegan?

I'm doing some international traveling soon. Destinations include South America, Asia, and Europe. I know it's not possible for me to speak the language in all of the countries I'm visiting, so I'm looking for a fool-proof way to ensure that I don't get served meat or animal products when I eat out at restaurants.

| [image: a picture of a menu in greek script] |
| --- |
| I really want to order something, but I can't read the menu. And the waiter doesn't speak the same language as me. |

I don't mind making a fool of myself. All I care about is that I don't end-up with animals or animal by-products on my plate.

What's the simplest way (that transcends the language barrier) to explain the plant-based diet when ordering food?

Comment: As soon as you have travel plans, ask at  https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=vegan+

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is difficult because:

1. If you say you're **vegetarian**, you may get served fish because many people don't realize it's not vegetarian
2. If you say you're **vegan**, lots of people won't understand and will think it's vegetarian.
3. If you say you **only eat plants**, lots of people will still serve you cheese and eggs
4. It you try to just **enumerate all of the things you can't eat**, you may skip some culturally-relevant items, (eg [crema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sour_cream) in Mexico, [paneer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paneer) in India, [leverpastej](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liver_p%C3%A2t%C3%A9) in Sweden, or [furikake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furikake) with [bonito](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonito) flakes in Japan)

### Google Translate

The best thing to do is probably to just print a sheet of paper explaining veganism in the language of the country you're visiting before you go. Something like:

> Hello, I am vegan. I am allergic to food from animals. I can only eat plants.
>
> I cannot eat: meat, fish, eggs, cheese, ...
>
> I can eat: rice, beans, vegetables, fruits, mushrooms, nuts, seeds, grains, etc

It would be a good idea to just spend a few hours googling "vegan in country X" before you do this.

After reading from other people's experiences, try to **figure out what are the most common non-vegan ingredients** (eg milk derivatives, fish condiments, etc) served in that country and **add them to the list above** before you translate it.

### Vegan Passport

The Vegan Society maintains a little book called the [Vegan Passport](https://www.vegansociety.com/resources/lifestyle/travel/vegan-passport) that is designed for this purpose.

[image: image of the vegan passport explaining veganism in english and catalan]

I haven't owned one, but my understanding is that they translate what veganism is in every language specifically for this purpose: so you can hand it to your waitress/waiter and they'll know what you can and cannot eat.

As far as I know, they take into account culture here, so they will specifically point out commonly-used ingredients for the given country that you cannot eat.

Answer (score 0):

"*I'm looking for a fool-proof way to ensure that I don't get served meat or animal products when I eat out at restaurants.*"

You could try translating this into all required languages:

"**I don't eat any part of an animal, bird, or fish, or any food that comes from one**".

In any language, that sentence would probably only use words in the top few hundred.

But this meaning is not easy to communicate using sign language that everyone would understand.